# Disable hardware button

Tags: android, android-studio, hardware

I have a phone with additional button with KEYCODE_FUNCTION. This button is used on this phone only for screenshots or starting other app. Now I want to launch my programm with this button and disable it when my programm is running.
I've tried to override onKeyUp and onKeyDown event. I can easely do this for volume buttons but can't for power button and this function button. How can I disable it?

Comment: I have this exception:
Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_FUNCTION, scanCode=249, metaState=META_FUNCTION_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=4211690, downTime=4211690, deviceId=5, source=0x101 }

Comment: Ask the manufacturer. Nobody else can help you.